# Does BMW use piezo-injectors for all their diesel engines since N57?

Tags: bmw, diesel

I've heard rumors that since piezo-injectors in N57s proven to be unreliable, BMW switched back to solenoid-type injectors in later engines.

Now I see piezo-type in B57 specs.

My question is what type of injectors are used in BMW *diesel* engines since N57, and how reliable are they (i.e., are they all tend to leak and flood an engine when fail, like first models were; and their reliability in general compared to solenoid-type)?

Also, what approximate mileage resource piezo-injectors have? Although this is not an exact parameter, and it's more about an experience, I'd like to know at what mileage on average they require replacement for the first time. Is it 50k, 100k, or 200k miles/kilometers? Should I reserve funds for them when purchasing a car 100k miles old?

Can they be repaired at shop, or they are one and done?

Comment: Welcome to Mechanics.SE. Your question about "how reliable are they" in the third sentence may be a little broad. Can you define what exactly you are asking for in reliability? Also, in the fourth sentence you want to know the mileage. I'm not sure what you're asking here? Is this for mileage of the vehicle using the piezo-injectors, or how many miles can we expect them to last? If just mileage of the vehicle, that'd be dependent on the vehicle model itself. For repaired, are you asking if they can be owner repaired, or if they can be sent somewhere for refurbishment or are they one and done?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thank you! I've edited the question, hope it is more exact now.

Comment: Could you better explain what you mean by "approximate mileage resource" ... it is not quite clear what you are asking there. It's not a term I'm used to seeing, so am trying to clarify to avoid confusion (I think everything else looks pretty good!)

Comment: Well, for a little information for you, the injector part number is: [BOSCH 0445117030](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=BOSCH+0445117030) ... Looks like BMW uses it in all of their diesel vehicles: Series 1, Series 2, 3 Series, Series 4, 5 Series, 6 Series, Series 7, X1, X3, X4, X5, X6 ... that's quite a few of them.

Comment: After some googling I found that almost every diesel engine had its own injectors, and there were few revisions for each.